# Redirection to Desktop site based on user-agent in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, desktop, user-agent

I have a mobile website https://example.com. I want to redirect desktop browsers to desktop.example.com using the .htaccess. I guess I need to use the user-agent of the browser. If possible, I want the redirection to be transparent. As I'm on the same domain, I guess it is possible.

I'm struggling to compose my rewrite rule. Can anyone help me?

Would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting closer I think..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\smobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://desktop.example.com [L,R=302]
```

But now I'm looking for a way to make the redirection transparent!